# How to search data from json in input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a url of a json file . In search input field when will type any pincode, then pin code suggestion should be show.

Here is my url ,

> https://data.gov.in/api/datastore/resource.json?resource_id=6176ee09-3d56-4a3b-8115-21841576b2f6&api-key=.

Please suggest me the steps or idea about this.

and, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better to keep your API Key secret...

Comment: You are looking for an autocomplete input field. Lots of ways to implement it. Google is your friend.

Comment: right, but it's a free service API.

Comment: In google , I can find lots of forums. But I want to know the appropriate way or simple way for this.

Comment: Sure, but anyone is now able to use your key for whatever… Maybe there is a rate limit or something else.

Comment: http://easyautocomplete.com/guide

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

```js
$(function () {
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://data.gov.in/api/datastore/resource.json?resource_id=6176ee09-3d56-4a3b-8115-21841576b2f6&api-key=<app key>",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          response($.map(data.records, function (item) {
            if (item.pincode.indexOf($("#tags").val()) == 0)
              return {
                label: item.pincode, // built the label like you want
                value: item.pincode
              };
          }));
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Iincode: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: When I search in input field , I get all search result. I want that if I search 811214 the I should get 811214 suggestion only instead of all  suggestion list.

Comment: @SandeepKumar Snippet updated. Now when you get the data a filter is applied to limit the suggestion